# Mapping entity properties to other entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, adventureworks

Inside the AdventureWorks database we have Individuals, Contacts and Customers.
These 3 tables are related. My goal is to get the FirstName, LastName and Email up on the Customers when I call them.

Is there a way to resolve this with mappings?

Thanks in advance.
Kyor

EDIT: Structure:
[image: Structure of the table]

Comment: My brain lacks a AdventureWorks database, so could you add the table structure and tell what you want to fetch from which table?

Comment: Hi Kyor, what is your architecture?  POCO, Code First or Model/DB first?  And to make sure we are clear, you want Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName...? Are you open to Customer.Contact.FirstName...(ignoring Demographics & ModifiedDate payload)?  FYI -- You could map your Customer (or alike) object to the Contact table with only First/Last/Email properties.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Model/DB first. I would like to have Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName and Customer.Email to work with, ignoring the rest. Mapping customer to contact isn't working because the contactID and customerID arn't 1-1 relationship. The modelbuilder also complains about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1) Using [Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx)

```
 var customers = context.Customer.Include("Individual.Contact");
```

Then you can access the properties by: `customers.First().Individual.Contact.FirstName;`

2) Projecting to a new Type

```
  var customers = from c in context.Customer
                  select new NewCustomerType
                  {
                    Customer = c,
                    FirstName = c.Individual.Contact.FirstName,
                    LastName = .Individual.Contact.LastName,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                  };
```

Comment: The problem is that i'm using it against MVC 3 - Razor and I want to avoid creating a custom customer object at all costs. Is there any possibility in mapping in the modelbrowser or XML behind?

Comment: @KyorCode - You could create a View on the database.

Comment: There are crud operations in the database through for this object, so a view ain't possible because it's in need of a primary key.